# DCC MGarch Likelihood

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, garch

The problem is quite simple but I somehow got stuck, so any help would be highly appreciated. 
In R I fitted a DCC MGARCH in 2 (M=2) dimensions as follows:
`

```
uspec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1), submodel = NULL, 
                                         external.regressors = NULL, variance.targeting = FALSE),
                   mean.model     = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), external.regressors = NULL),
                   distribution.model = "std", start.pars = list(), fixed.pars = list())

dcc.spec = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(M, uspec)), dccOrder = c(1,1), distribution = "mvt")

dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.spec, data = X, out.sample = N.OOS, fit.control = list(eval.se=T))
```

X is my dataset of N + N.OOS rows and M (=2) columns and I want to keep N.OOS observations for out of sample testing. The innovations are multivariate t distributed.

Now I want to recalculate the log likelihood.

```
dcc.H <- dcc.fit@mfit$H
dcc.mean <- c(dcc.fit@mfit$coef[1], dcc.fit@mfit$coef[7]) 
values = rep(0, N)
for (i in 1:N){
  values[i] <- dmvt(x = X[i,], delta = dcc.mean, sigma = dcc.H[1:2, 1:2, i], df = coef(dcc.fit)[15])
}
sum(values)
```

However, when I compare the likelihood that are calculated by the dccfit routine (`dcc.fit@mfit$log.likelihoods`)  and my manual recalculation (`values`) I get small (but large enough such that it is not a numerical issue) discrepancies. Shouldn't the likelihoods that I calculated manually be the same as the one that were calculated by the dccfit routine? Can anybody hint me at where my thinking is wrong?

I can provide the data too, if necessary.

**EDIT:**
Of course one needs to appropriately scale the dispersion matrix with the degrees of freedom. With the following change the log-likelihoods are much closer but still not exactly the same:

```
 dcc.df <- coef(dcc.fit)[15]
 values = rep(0, 503)
 for (i in 1:503){
 values[i] <- dmvt(x = X[i,], delta = dcc.mean, 
              sigma = dcc.H[1:2, 1:2, i] * (dcc.df - 2)/dcc.df
                        , df = dcc.df)
}
```

Still, I am a bit puzzled as to why I am not getting the exact same values. Any ideas?